# sed to replace the ip addresses in /opt/data/hosts in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I want that script to replace the "IP addresses" in the hosts file by deleting the existing IP addresses.

My hosts file contains the below entry..

```
[buildservers]
10.10.10.01
10.10.10.02
10.10.10.03
[buildservers:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=root
```

My expected result after running the script

```
[buildservers]
10.10.10.11
10.10.10.12
10.10.10.13
[buildservers:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=root
```

and below is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=/opt/data/hosts
if [ -f $hosts ] ; then
    echo "Hosts file exists"
    update_host
    else
    echo "Hosts: No such file"
    exit 0;
 fi
update_host() {
sed -i '/^\[buildservers\].*/!b;n;c$1' $hosts
}
```

but it is replacing only the first IP address and not deleting the existing IP addresses.

Please provide the correct "sed" to do this..

Comment: don't you need the `g` flag?

Comment: `sed '/\[buildservers\]/ {n;N;N;s/\.0/.1/g}'` should work for your desired results but is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative using GNU awk (for inplace editing)

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=/opt/data/hosts

update_host(){
  awk -i inplace ' 
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="."}
    f { 
    if (/\[buildservers:vars\]/) 
      f=0
    else $4 = $4+10
    } 
  /\[buildservers\]/{ f=1 } 
  { print } 
  ' "$hosts"
}

if [ -f $hosts ] ; then
  echo "Hosts file exists"
  update_host
else
  echo "Hosts: No such file"
  exit 0;
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. `${REPLACE}` should be all IP addresses to be replaced and separated by a newline

```
sed "/^\[buildservers\]/bx :x; /[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/d;by :y; 1a${REPLACE}"
```